# Structure template replacement for #+ATTR_LATEX?

Tags: org-mode

I had previously used an old-style structure template `<r` to insert `#+ATTR_LATEX:`  (my own custom setting).

This style has been deprecated: structure templates now support *only* BEGIN_ / END_ style.

I do not want to have to type `#+ATTR_LATEX:`  for every embedded image or table.

What is a good replacement for this really very often-used functionality?

Comment: [`yasnippet`](https://github.com/joaotavora/yasnippet/blob/master/README.mdown)?

Comment: Yeah, I guess yasnippet... never needed it before. Thanks.